# LaTeX figure insert problem

Tags: floats, errors

I am a beginner in LaTeX, when I wanted to insert a graph into the document, it shows several errors, could anyone help me with this, what should I do to fix the error?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}



\title{problem}
\author{xr}
\date{25th.Feb.202}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{number.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

%line 440: Undefined control sequence. }
%line 11: Extra \fi. \begin{document}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Instead of images, please place the code what you tried so far, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it again

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: If I use an example image, your code works to me, which error do you get?

Comment: By the way, it is a bad idea to name graphic files by numbers. The same goes for labels.

Comment: Just an addition to Johannes' comment: it is not that numbers are wrong, just that they in this case soon gers confusing. What if you add another image before this one, then that has number one and this one is number two, it is hard to remember which label refers to which thing when you name them like this. Better to give names that are independent of the numbering

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your file other than we do not have a file called `1.png` to test it with, and you do not say what errors you get so it is impossible to help. If asking about an error please copy the exact error message from the log file and add it as a code block to your question, so line breaks are preserved in the message.

Comment: hiya, i have 3 errors. the first one is undefined control sequence. the second one is Extra \fi.\begin{document}, the last one is Package pdftex.def Error: File `1.png' not found: using draft setting. ...ncludegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{1.png}, i am sure the picture is in the same folder with the tex file

Comment: i have edited my question again with error information, thank you guys!

Comment: Please post the exact error and format it as code (by indenting four lines or hitting `{}`) such that line endings are respected. TeX breaks the line at the undefined control sequence and we need to know which is it. Anyway, it looks like you have an old distribution. Did you try an update?

Answer (score 1):

this problem has already been solved. the code is correct. it is the problem of the package, it runs well after i updated the package in MiKTex console.

Answer (score 0):

The curly braces after \includegraphics should contain the path to the graphic you want to insert, e.g.

```
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{myfigure.png}
```

So the error message tells you that it is not able to find a figure called "1.png" because you put {1} there. The rest of the error messages is just further errors because it fails to include the graphic.

Just provide the correct path there and the error should go away.

Comment: hiya, I have changed the filename, and it is found now, however, it still shows 2 errors, 1.undefined control sequence, 2. Extra \fi. \begin{document}. have you got anymore idera? thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that what you show is the only code you use? It compiles fine for me. The error looks like you messed up some command (that's why it says undefined control sequence)